# My Visual Studio 2022 C++ project is not writing to console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have created a boiler plate Visual Studio CMake C++ project using the project wizard.

It created a header and source file, and a CMakeList.txt for me.

I created a simple base class that ctor just writes to console. I have an additional console write in the main.

My main function is as follows...

```
// CMakeProject1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "CMakeProject1.h"
#include "Base.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Base* base = new Base();
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a breakpoint set on the Base() ctor and the line after. Both of the breakpoints are hitting when I hit F5 to debug.

The expected print statements cannot be observed anywhere. I have looked in the "command window" tab, and it is empty.

In the 'output' window tab, the output is as follows....

```
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\me\Scott\source\repos\CMakeProject1\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeProject1\CMakeProject1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'CMakeProject1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x2ae8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How (where) can I observe print statements in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: When you execute a console application in Visual Studio, it's run in an actual console window, not in the IDE itself. You should see that new window on both your desktop and on the taskbar, especially if you suspend execution by hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: And if you aren't getting that there are too many possible problems to list. You'll have to narrow the problem down with more information in the question. And how you you figure out what information you need to add to the question? Sadly most of the time you won't know until after you've solved the problem. As a result, IDE questions have a staggeringly low success rate.

Comment: If you don't get a popup cmd.exe window my guess is your antivirus is the problem. On windows 11 for me I get a "Visual Studio Debug Console" window that shares the same tab as Windows Terminal (which I pretty much always have open). This is for any console application I launch in Visual Studio Community 2019. 2022 should have the same behavior but I use it much less often.

Comment: @drescherjm This is my first time doing dev on Windows in a long time, and I love how your comment is such a warm refresher to Windows lol!

Comment: If remove the breakpoints, is there a CMD window popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::cout puts input to the stdout file descriptor.

Therefore, you need to look at the console window that opens with the launch of the application, and not the output window in Visual Studio (By default, the console displays the data written to the stdout file descriptor).

Output window tab shows info passed to debugger via [OutputDebugStringA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa) WinAPI function